# ERROR : Unable to load DLL 'tcl84.DLL'

Tags: c#

I am using 'DllImport("tcl84.Dll")'  in c# dot net and i have put tcl84.Dll in  Windows\system32\tcl84 dll. and still im facing the error that

> "Unable to load DLL 'tcl84.DLL': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Now what should i do?

Comment: It's possible **tcl84.Dll** depends on other .DLLs that could not be located/loaded?

Comment: What happens when you put the DLL into your bin\debug folder instead of the system32 folder?

Comment: The error is also same when i pul DLL in bin/debug folder

Comment: Did you delete the version in System32 before? If that's the case it could still be a 32/64 bit issue. If your application runs in 64 bit mode and the dll is 32 bit it won't be able to load. Also it could depend on other dlls missing on your system.

Comment: yes i have deleted the version from System32 before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution 1**
This could be a 32/64-bit issue. If you have a 32-bit application running on a 64-bit Windows, the DLLs will be loaded from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead of `C:\Windows\System32`.

So you could try to make the application `Any CPU` or copy it to `bin\debug` instead of a system folder.

Also if your application is running in 64-bit mode (x64 or `Any CPU` or a 64-bit Windows), but the DLL is 32-bit only, it won't load either, as you can not use a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit application. You then need to compile your application as 32-bit explicitly.

**Possible solution 2**
The DLL itself requires other DLLs that are not available on your system. Make sure that all dependencies for the DLL are resolved.